# excel report not download, what need to do more?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

1. Below code works well when I use a Submit button and put Excel export code in controller POST action.
2. Now I don't want post back and move the code like below, but now report is not download, although controller action "ExcelExport" called as expected, but report is not downloaded? Kindly suggest whats wrong here?

**Model**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Product(int id, string name, string description, decimal price)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Price = price;
    }

    static readonly List<Product> AllProducts = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product(1, "Games Console", "Fun for all the family", 199.99m),
            new Product(2, "MP3 player", "Listen to your favourite tunes on the move", 99.99m),
            new Product(3, "Smart Phone", "Apps, apps, apps", 399.99m),
            new Product(4, "Digital Photo frame", "All your photos in one beautiful frame", 49.99m),
            new Product(5, "E-book reader", "Take your favourite books on the move with you", 149.99m),
            new Product(6, "DVD Box Set", "All of season one plus exclusive extras", 39.99m)
    };

    public static List<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return AllProducts;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult ExcelExport()
    {
        var products = Product.GetAllProducts();

        var grid = new GridView();
        grid.DataSource = from p in products
                          select new
                          {
                              ProductName = p.Name,
                              SomeProductId = p.Id
                          };
        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");

        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        grid.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());

        Response.End();

        return Content("tr");
    }
```

**View**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


<div id="rptExport" style="display: none">
</div>

<input type="button" id="ExportExcelButton" value="Export To Excel" onclick="ExportExcel()" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
//global cache false
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

function ExportExcel() {
    //block the UI until the request is rendered
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h3><b><img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/loading.gif")" />Please wait while Processing</b></h3>' });

    $('#rptExport').load('@Url.Action("ExcelExport", "Home")', function (data) {
        var urlFile = "";
        if (data != '') {
            debugger;
            //unblock the UI     
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you rendering HTML and pretending that it's an Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use AJAX to download a file.
You need to use a regular page request.

Comment: Is it wrong that when I see 'postback' and MVC together, I cringe?  I believe he could just have a normal GET request to download the file, no POSTing needed as he is not submitting data.